# Can't load class by dependency injection in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I'm trying to use dependenc injection in Symfony, but it doesnt work for mee :-(

**I have this controller:**

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

/**
 * Class UsersController
 */
class UsersController extends Controller
{    
    ....
    public function indexAction(){
        ....
        $userManager = $this->get('user_manager');
        $userManager->createUser();
        ...    
    }    
    ....
}
```

**This want this class to inject:**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\DI;    

use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class UserManager
{
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager){
        $this->em = $entityManager;
    }

    public function createUser(){
        $user = new User();
        ....
        $this->em->persist($user);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
}
```

**My services.yml**

```
services:
    user_manager:
        class: AppBundle\DI\UserManager
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

**But i still have this error:**

> Attempted to load class "UserManager" from namespace "AppBundle\DI".
>   Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Could someone advise me, where is a mistake? I'm starting with symfony...

Thanks.

Comment: Check one more time if UserManager.php exist in folder AppBundle/DI. In many cases there is typo in the filenames or namespaces, or class names.

Comment: could you indicate the whole path to UserManager.php file?

Comment: Of course that did not exist: D I thought it sufficient to have an appropriate namespace, thanks

Comment: If it doesn't exists, you need to namespace it properly or to move it in the right directory with correct namespace ;)

Comment: @DominikVoda namespace and path needs to be consistent if you want the autoloader to find your classes.